# trying RPG in windows form, trying to get value from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

So guys, I created a `CreateChar : Form` and created a class `BaseHero` hero.

First I need to set my hero status from createCharForm. How do I connect it to another form? So that I can access the class value easily...

```
public partial class CreateChar : Form
{
    private SoundPlayer backgroundMusic;
    //public  int HP
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        int isi;
    //        isi = (int)hpUpDown.Value;
    //        return isi;
    //    }
    //}
    //public int Mana
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        int isi;
    //        isi = (int)manaUpDown.Value;
    //        return isi;
    //    }
    //}
    //public int Damage
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        int isi;
    //        isi = (int)damageUpDown.Value;
    //        return isi;
    //    }
    //}
    //public int Def
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        int isi;
    //        isi = (int)defUpDown.Value;
    //        return isi;
    //    }
    //}
    public CreateChar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void CreateChar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundMusic = new SoundPlayer("createChar.wav");
        backgroundMusic.PlayLooping();
    }

    private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BaseHero Hero = new BaseHero();
        Hero.Hitpoints = (int)hpUpDown.Value;
        Hero.Mana = (int)manaUpDown.Value;
        Hero.Damage = (int)damageUpDown.Value;
        Hero.Defense = (int)defUpDown.Value;


    }
 }


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BaseHero danang = new BaseHero();
    monsterAir pugna = new monsterAir();
    monsterAir dua = new monsterAir();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //testTextBox.Text = pugna.Hitpoints.ToString();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = danang.Hitpoints.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = danang.Exp.ToString();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox3.Text = dua.Hitpoints.ToString();
        textBox4.Text = dua.Expearned.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        danang.Attack(dua);
        danang.checkMonster(dua);
    }

    private void btn_buatbaru_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateChar formCharacterBaru = new CreateChar();
        if (formCharacterBaru.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            BaseHero Hero = new BaseHero();
            Hero.Hitpoints = formCharacterBaru.HP;
            Hero.Mana = formCharacterBaru.Mana;
            Hero.Damage = formCharacterBaru.Damage;
            Hero.Defense = formCharacterBaru.Def;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make the forms reference each other is to create them and passed them in the constructor.

```
Form1 frm1;
public CreateChar(Form1 f1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frm1 = f1;
}
```

And inside the form1 constructor:

```
CreateChar cc;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cc = new CreateChar(this);

    //testTextBox.Text = pugna.Hitpoints.ToString();

}
```

Comment: how i suppose create the class?